# Let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=1/(5+i+x_n)$ where $n=2,3,4,...$. Show that the sequence converges and find its limit.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $x_1=1$ and  $x_{n+1}=1/(5+i+x_n)$ where $n=2,3,4,...$. Show that the sequence converges and find its limit.

I did the first couple iterations, however, I am having trouble finding a pattern, much less being able to prove convergence. Can someone point me in the write direction of how to proceed?

Comment: If you *assume* the sequence converges, you can find the limit $x$ by letting $n\to\infty$ on both sides of your recurrence relation, which gives you a quadratic equation in $x$. One of the two solutions will be the limit. Of course, you still have to figure out which, and prove the sequence actually converges to it.

Comment: I computed the two possible limits. How do I figure out which one it is?

Comment: That is why I only gave a comment, not an answer. I don't have a solid answer for you. Just a hint that I hoped would push you in the right direction to find one. You will need to show that the sequence starts to cluster around one of the answers. It may take calculating several values before you can see it staying closer to one than the other. Then additional work to prove that it actually converges to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the root of smallest module of the equation $x^2+(5+i)x-1=0$ be (hopefully)  $$ w=\frac{1}{2}\left(-5-i+\sqrt{14+\sqrt{221}}\left(1+i\frac{\sqrt{221}-14}{5}\right)\right)$$
then, the other root is $-1/w$. Now, define
$$z_n=\frac{x_n-w}{x_n+1/w}$$
Clearly we have
$$z_{n+1}=w\frac{ 1-(5+i)w-wx_n}{ w+5+ i+x_n}=-w^2\frac{x_n-w}{x_n+1/w}=-w^2 z_n$$
Thus $(z_n)$ is geometric and converges to  $0$ since $|w|<1$. Finally since,
$$x_n-w=\frac{z_n}{1-z_n}\left(w+\frac{1}{w}\right)$$
we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n= w.$$

Comment: equation $x^2+(5+i)x-1=0$ can be used if you know $|x_n|$ is either decreasing and has a lower bound or is increasing and has an upper bound.So how did you show either of these???

Comment: @kilimanjaro, I didn't use what you are talking about!! These are complex numbers, there is no order here to talk about monotonous sequences.

Comment: Please check that I typed $|x_n|$ not $x_n$.

Comment: Am I not right?

Comment: @kilimanjaro, Please check the question is about $x_n$  and not $|x_n|$, because you can deduce nothing from the convergence of $(|x_n|)$ about  the convergence of $(x_n)$,( of course unless the limit is zero, which is not the case here), After all there is no logical flow in my solution, you just need to study it.:)

Comment: Yes,question is about $x_n$ but in $x_n$ ,order can't be defined.And there is more to that ,if somehow $|x_n|$ is shown to be convergent then $x_n$ can be shown to be convergent(Absolute convergence).So first,shouldn't you show $|x_n|$ is either decreasing and has a lower bound or is increasing and has an upper bound?

Comment: @kilimanjaro, This completely wrong look at $x_n=e^{i n}$.